# Python watchdog - return username of the user which trigger events

Tags: python-3.x, python-watchdog

I have a Windows file server which are running [watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/) to monitor a filepath. And my goal is to know which of my domain users are making changes in this filepath.

I Have tried the following methods, which are only returning the username  running the console 'administrator', and not the domain user which are triggering.

```
print ("File changed - %s - By user %s"  % (event.src_path, os.getenv('username')))
```

And

```
print ("File changed - %s - By user %s"  % (event.src_path, getpass.getuser()))
```

Every machine in my environment are running Windows.

Any idea on how I can return the domain user?

Comment: Could you try http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-the-owner-of-a-file.html?